# Is the restriction map continuous?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, jet-bundles

Consider $C^{\infty}(U, \mathbb{R}^{k})$ and $C^{\infty}(V, \mathbb{R}^{k})$, where $V\subset U $, with $U$ and $V$ open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true that the restriction

\begin{align} R:C^{\infty}(U, \mathbb{R}^{k}) &\rightarrow  C^{\infty}(V, \mathbb{R}^{k})\\ f &\mapsto f \big|_{V}\end{align} is continuous?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not surjective. Concoct your own example; say $f\in C^\infty(V)$ and $f$ blows up at a boundary point of $V$...

I'm not sure what the "Whitney" topology is. The standard topology on $C^\infty(U)$ is metrizable, with  $f_n\to f$ if and only if $D^\alpha f_n\to D^\alpha f$ uniformly on every compact subset of $U$. With this topology it's trivial from the definition that the restriction is continuous. (Say $f_n\to f$ in $C^\infty(U)$. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $V$. Then $K$ is a compact subset of $U$, so...)

Comment: What about continuity?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here is a good explanation about the Whitney topology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_topologies. More informations are in Stable Mappings and Their Singularities by Guillemin and Golubistky pag. 42. I'm not sure if with this Topology this space is metrizable. If this is true, my problem is solved.